# Incorrect range width in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-api

I get this result:

> [[619, 2016-12-06, 03:08:04], [620, 2016-12-06, 03:08:18], [618, 2016-12-06, 03:09:40], [224, 2016-12-06, 03:29:14], [224, 2016-12-06, 03:41:55], [616, 2016-12-06, 06:44:59], [51, 2016-12-06, 07:05:21], [617, 2016-12-06, 07:12:50], [622, 2016-12-06, 07:29:26], [614, 2016-12-06, 07:31:01], [358, 2016-12-06, 07:39:52], [50, 2016-12-06, 07:41:43], [345, 2016-12-06, 07:58:30], [479, 2016-12-06, 08:02:57], [374, 2016-12-06, 08:29:07], [594, 2016-12-06, 12:18:40], [619, 2016-12-06, 16:17:33],[...]]

which is 272 all in all.

I try to paste in Google sheets using script with this code:

```
function addTimeToSheet(data){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("11-_0QwEV_NGRY5nJUsOwyDxcmPGPXkLv636dQQ-SA5o");
  var sheets = ss.getSheetByName("TempKawit").getRange(1, 1).setValues([data]);

  return data;
}
```

There is no data in the sheet. I just want to put the data there temporarily and if the script is ran again, it'll just overwrite what was there. But on running the script, even on the first run without any data in the sheet, it gives me an error like so:

```
Incorrect range width, was 272 but should be 1.
```

But if I code the function like this:

```
function addTimeToSheet(data){
  Logger.log(data);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("11-_0QwEV_NGRY5nJUsOwyDxcmPGPXkLv636dQQ-SA5o");
  var sheets = ss.getSheetByName("TempKawit");
  sheets.getRange(1, sheets.getLastColumn()+1,data.length,3).setValues([data]);

  return data;
}
```

I get this error:

```
Incorrect range height, was 1 but should be 272
```

Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
function addTimeToSheet(data){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("11-_0QwEV_NGRY5nJUsOwyDxcmPGPXkLv636dQQ-SA5o");
  var noOfRow = data.length
  var noOfCol = data[0].length
  var sheets = ss.getSheetByName("TempKawit").getRange(1, 1,noOfRow,noOfCol).setValues(data);

  return data;
}
```

Correct syntax :**setValues(data)** and **not:** setValues([data])